# Doctrine2 + Zend Framework 2 - EntitiesManager as variable in Controller

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I want to set EntitiesManager instance available on my Controller. I want the Instance available with $this->em on Controller. This is my configuration :

module.config.php

```
[...]
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'application_entities' => array(
            'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities'
            ),
        ),
    ),
),  
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'application' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
        'Application\Controller\IndexController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'em' => 'doctrine_em',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

protected $em;

public function setEm(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction() {
    $user1 = $this->em->find('\Application\Entity\User', 1);
    var_dump($user1->getFullname());
}
```

I got this error : "**Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object**". It seem than EntityManager is not correctly instantiate.

What Am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't use Doctrine, but it could be you haven't got a definition in the DI for 'doctrine_em', not sure if the module adds an entry for this

Comment: Yes 'doctrine_em' is not related to anything, how i should relate it to EntityManager ?

Answer (score 0):

- You dont need anything in the module config
- You edit the Module.php, onbootstrap function

  ```
  public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e) {
       $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
       $em = $serviceManager;

       $controllerLoader = $serviceManager->get('ControllerLoader');
       $controllerLoader->addInitializer(function ($controller) use ($em) {
           if (method_exists($controller, 'setEm')) {
              $controller->setEm($em);
           }
       });
  }
  ```
- the controller stays as you have it, with the $em field, and the setEm method

  ```
  //..
  protected $em;

  public function setEm(EntityManager $em) {
          $this->em = $em;
          return $this;
  }
  //..
  ```